# Bootstrap Well Component Not Containing Content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html for my page. I'm trying to figure out why the well component has the content not being containing in the element. Its starting outside the element the well.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>School 1</li>
                <li>School 2</li>       
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>School 1</li>
                <li>School 2</li>       
            </ul>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>

.well {
    background-color: #9999FF;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the well class to the outer div. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k7v1q2t/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="row well">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>School 1</li>
                <li>School 2</li>       
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>School 1</li>
                <li>School 2</li>       
            </ul>
        </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap, all `col-*` elements are floated left, this means that the parent (i.e. the `row`) doesn't fully surround the children. You should try to keep wells inside the `col-*` elements. Otherwise you can also make the well surround the entire `row` which may also achieve what you wish.

Comment: Do you agree with the answer from EatPeanutButter

Comment: Possibly, but I dislike modifying Bootstrap elements.